# Update element in array in mongo db

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a document structured like this:

```
{
        "shedule": [
          {
            "SUN": {
              "status": false,
              "task": []
            }
          },
          {
            "MON": {
              "status": false,
              "task": []
            }
          },
        ]
      }
```

How to update status to false and push new element to task array in `sun`  object.

Here is the expected output.

```
{
        "shedule": [
          {
            "SUN": {
              "status": true,
              "task": [1,2]
            }
          },
          {
            "MON": {
              "status": false,
              "task": []
            }
          },
        ]
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your SUM always at the first place, this is the answer:

```
db.collection.update(
    {},
    { 
        $push: { 
            "shedule.0.SUN.task": { 
                $each: [ NumberInt(1), NumberInt(2) ] } },
        $set: { "shedule.0.SUN.status": true } 
    }
)
```